# Bold Style not applied to textview android

Tags: android, textview, android-actionbar, text-styling

I'm using action bar with custom view for title to be able to add Title and Subtitle

I need to set Title Style to Bold, When I make it in the XML layout it works fine, but I need to set it from code using

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

but it does not work, can anyone please help

Comment: Ideally it should work. This may sound mundane but can you check if it gets reset by somewhere after you set it to bold the first time in your Java file.

Comment: Thank you for help, yes it was changed in another activity

Answer (score 1):

Ideally it should work. This may sound mundane but can you check if it gets reset somewhere after you set it to bold the first time in your Java file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to display HTML codes in textviews

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>BOLD WORDS HERE</b>"));
```